# How to pass the right Context to a DataTemplate within an ItemTemplate of a WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

in my WPF app there is a `ListView` defined as follows:

```
            <ListView
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListSource}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ParameterIconSize" />
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="Auto"
                                MaxWidth="100"
                                SharedSizeGroup="ParameterDescriptionSize" />
                            <ColumnDefinition
                                Width="Auto"
                                MinWidth="40"
                                SharedSizeGroup="ParameterValueSize" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            MaxHeight="50"
                            Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Content="{Binding Path=RenderValue, Converter={StaticResource RenderObjToValueConverter}}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RenderTemplateSelector}"
                            />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I've defined everything in the `Resources` as follows:

```
            <!--  TEXT  -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextValueTemplate">
            <DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource VM}">
                <TextBlock
                    MaxWidth="75"
                    Margin="5,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="Red"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock
                            MaxWidth="100"
                            Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
              </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!--  IMAGE  -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageValueTemplate">
            <DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource VM}">
                <Image MaxHeight="50" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentValueImage}" />               
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!--  COMBO BOX  -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboValueTemplate">
            <DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource VM}">
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    MaxWidth="75"
                    Margin="5,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock
                            MaxWidth="100"
                            Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
                <ComboBox/>
                
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <sel:ParameterVisualizationTemplateSelector
            x:Key="RenderTemplateSelector"
            ComboTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ComboValueTemplate}"
            GraphicTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ImageValueTemplate}"
            TextTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextValueTemplate}" />
```

Everything compiles and runs, but then I am not able to correctly pass the `ListViewItem` to the inner datatemplate.

What I want to do is to be able to change what is shown based on some logic (not shown here) between an image, some text and a combobox. What's going inside those controls is defined in the `ListViewItem`. As you can see, I tried to write a converter that return the corresponding type (image, text, list of data), but I am missing the link between the various `DataTemplates`.

FINAL EDIT: Based on the answer from @mm8 I found that the real issue was not passing the context, but that the property passed wasn't correctly processed and then no value would be set up whilst not giving any binding error.

Comment: In order to bind to the ListViewItem parent element of the elements in the ItemTemplate, use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}`. As a note, when you do not set a ListView's `View` property, use the simpler ListBox, the base class of ListView.

Comment: @MarcomattiaMocellin: So what is the "right" context in this case? The converted `RenderValue`? Then you should remove `DataContext="{StaticResource VM}"` from the templates. The `DataContext` of the root element in the `ContentTemplate` is the `Content` of the `ContentControl`.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, but then the ListViewItem doesn't expose my properties, and I get several binding errors.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, the context would be it. So, if I understand correctly, the "dependency" chain is something like

control <- textItemtemplate <- ListViewItemTemplate <- Viewmodel, so the final control automatically "inherits" the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `DataContext="{StaticResource VM}"` in your template, you are effectively "overriding" the default `DataContext` which is the current item in the `ListSource` source collection of the `ListView`.

> So, if I understand correctly, the "dependency" chain is something like control <- textItemtemplate <- ListViewItemTemplate <- Viewmodel, so the final control automatically "inherits" the object?

You bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to a source collection property called `ListSource`:

```
 <ListView ... ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListSource}">
```

The default `DataContext` of the root element (the `Grid` in this case) in the `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate` will then be an element in `ListSource`.

This means that if `ListSource` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` you can bind directly to any public property of the type `T` in the `ItemTemplate` provided that you don't explictly set the `DataContext` property somewhere in the template.

So `Icon` is supposed to be a property of `T` (whatever your type `T` is) in your example:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0"
       MaxHeight="50"
       Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
```

If you for example remove `DataContext="{StaticResource VM}"` from the `TextValueTemplate`, the binding to `Description` should work provided that there is a `Description` property defined in the object returned from the converter of the `RenderValue` property.